# How Intertwined are Two Sets of Points?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given two sets of points on the plane, of potentially different cardinalities:

$\mathcal{X}=\left\{\mathbf{x}_1, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{|\mathcal{X}|}\right\}$,

$\mathcal{Y}=\left\{\mathbf{y}_1, \dots, \mathbf{y}_{|\mathcal{Y}|}\right\}$,

what is a good measure of how "intertwined" the two sets are?

The measure should be $0$ if $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are **[linearly separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability)**, and become larger the more "intertwined" they are. I do not have a precise definition of "intertwined" (if I did, the measure would follow easily!), but I would be happy with any reasonable one.

For bonus points, could the measure be extended to an arbitrary number of sets of points $k$, and/or to arbitrary dimension $n$?

Thanks in advance for any answers or references.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$
\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}
\newcommand{\Y}{\mathcal{Y}}
\newcommand{\CH}[1]{\mathrm{ConvexHull}\left(#1\right)}
\I(\X,\Y) = \frac{\Big(\mu\big(\CH{\X} \cap \CH{\X}\big)\Big)^2}{\mu\big(\CH{\X}\big) \cdot \mu\big(\CH{\Y}\big)}$$

where $\mu$ is the $n$-dimensional measure appropriate for space that contains $\X$ and $\Y$, and $\CH{A}$ is the convex hull of $A$, that is the smallest convex set that contains $A$ (i.e. the convex hull of three points is the *whole* triangle, not just the points).

This function $\I$ has maximum $1$ for $\CH{\X} = \CH{\Y}$ and minimum $0$ for sets such that the intersection of convex hulls has measure $0$. For example for $\X = [0,1]^2$ and $\Y = [-1,0]^2$ we have that $\X \cap \Y = \{(0,0)\}$ which has measure $0$, but $\X$ and $\Y$ are not linearly separable.

If you were to insist, this could be solved in two ways:

- Instead of $\X$ work with $\{B(x,\varepsilon) \mid x \in \X\}$ with some small $\varepsilon$ of your choosing. This has the undesirable property of being positive for linearly separable sets with distance smaller than $\varepsilon$.
- Add some discontinuous component like 
  $$f(\X,\Y) = 
  \begin{cases}
  0 &\text{ for } \CH{\X} \cap \CH{Y} = \varnothing \\
  1 &\text{ for } \CH{\X} \cap \CH{Y} \neq \varnothing
  \end{cases}$$
- Use multiple measures, that is, if $\mu_n$ is zero, maybe $\mu_{n-1}$ or $\ldots$ or $\mu_1$ or $\mu_0$ would be non-zero? You will need a few tweaks here (e.g. if one set is two-dimensional, the other is three-dimensional, and their intersection is one-dimensional), but it depends on what properties you would like to have.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: As the question does not ask for the measure to lie between $0$ and $1$, I think $\mu\big({\operatorname{Conv}}(\mathcal X)\cap\operatorname{Conv}(\mathcal Y)\big)$ would do just as well. :)

Comment: @RahulNarain Well, yes. However, my intention was to make the measure in $[k,k+1]$ if the sets intertwine as $k$-dimensional figures, but the formulae got too complicated.

Comment: @dtldarek Good idea. If I understand correctly, for points on 2-dimensional plane, $\mu$ would be represent the area. The problem with this measure is that the position of a single point can make the whole difference between the measure being $0$ and $1$. Ideally, I would like the measure to be not too sensitive to the position of a single point, especially if there are many other points.

Comment: @MGA You could always use $$\left(\bigcup_{x \in \mathcal{X}}B(x,\varepsilon)\right) \cap \mathrm{ConvexHull}(\mathcal{X})$$ for intersections (instead of just convex hull) inside $\mathcal{I}$. This way you could adjust with $\varepsilon$ how close points could be before they become "intertwined". The problem is that this measure could be zero for points that are far from linearly separable (before, if measure was 0, then some random shakes could make the sets separable).